# Which of these is a more efficient implementation of a multiple key, multiple value hash map?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, collections

I was wondering which in Java is a more efficient implementation of a multiple key/ multiple value hashmap:  A hashmap with lists as key/values was more efficient or a hashmap with objects as key/values and why? For example:

Lists as keys/values:

```
HashMap<List<Integer>,List<Double>> listmap = new   HashMap<List<Integer>,List<Double>>();
```

Objects as keys/values

```
HashMap<Object1,Object2> objectmap = new HashMap<Object1,Object2>(); // where Object 1 and 2 have fields for Integer keys and Double values, respectively
```

Thanks, in advance! ( Note: I did test this and found that objects were better, but I do not really understand why that is the case)

Edit: (how the object is implemented)

```
public class keys {

public  final int x;
public final int y;

public keys(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof keys)) return false;
    keys key = (keys) o;
    return x == key.x && y == key.y;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = x;
    result = 31 * result + y;
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a specific number of elements in the lists?  e.g. are these always pairs?

Comment: Did you also implement `hashCode` and `equals` in your custom objects? If yes, how did you do it?

Comment: @LouisWasserman In the key and value list, there are 2.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Here is the implementation of the object:

Comment: If that's the case, then objects representing pairs should definitely be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keys and values always have a specific number of elements, then writing your own objects is going to be more efficient: lists have boxing and array overhead necessary when they can contain an arbitrary number of elements, whereas you can avoid all that by writing your own specialized implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Collections (such as List) are designed to handle an unbounded (well, reasonably unbounded) collection of elements, and as a result they incur an overhead to their basic operations (hashCode, equals, etc), storing of primitives (boxing/unboxing), and memory footprint as opposed to a class written for a specific number of elements.

A key which only needs to hold 2 integers will thus be significantly more optimal if directly written as a class instead of being abstracted in a variable sized List object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have exactly two keys and they are `int`s, packing them into `long` like `(((long) x) << 32) | (y & 0xFFFFFFFFL)` and implementing a custom `Map` with unboxed primitive `long` keys, or picking up existing from Koloboke/fastutil/GS collections/HPPC/HPPC-RT library, would be definitely  faster.